# Interactive summation

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nARMB.jpg) programmed in Excel:

[image]

The variables you can change are **Points** and **Steps**. In the table there comes the value for each step until all the points/steps are given. The values beneath that has to be zero. I used the function *Numbervalue* to check some assumptions, but that didn't workout:

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(Previous_Cell) < POINTS;Previous_Cell+ POINTS_PER_CELL;0)
```

After the `2` points, the next cell becomes zero. But then the whole list starts over. So there has to be some function that says: If Previous_CELL = 0 then THIS_CELL = 0.

Comment: Can you show the formulas you have so far? At the moment this is not a question but more of an assignment. Please ask specific questions.

Comment: =IF(NUMBERVALUE(Previous_Cell) < POINTS;Previous_Cell+ POINTS_PER_CELL;0)

After the 2 points, the next cell becomes zero. But then the whole list start over. So there has to be some function that says: If Previous_CELL = 0 then THIS_CELL = 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Points` is in A1, in B6:

```
=IF(OR(SUM(B$5:B5)>B$2,B5=B$2),"",B$3*(MOD(ROW()-1,B$2)+1))
```

and in C6, with both copied down to suit:

```
=IF(OR(SUM(C$5:C5)>C$2,C5=C$2),"",C$3*(MOD(ROW()-6,C$2)+1))
```